# Getting undefined node.js code

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have this code below. Using the `readline` and `fs` module I am trying to search for a particular word in a file line by line and if that word exist push the contents of that word to an array but when I try to return this array I get an undefined. Any ideas?

```
var fs = require('fs');
var readline  = require('readline');

var reader = readline.createInterface({
    input: fs.createReadStream('MY_FILE_NAME.txt'),
});

function newDefineWord(reader1) {
  this.reader = reader1;
}



newDefineWord.prototype.define = function(searchTerm) {
      var arr = [];

      this.reader.on('line', function (line) {
          if (line.search(searchTerm)!== -1) {            
            arr.push(line);
            console.log(arr);
          }
      });

      return arr;

}

var word = new newDefineWord(reader);
console.log(word.define('libro'));
```

Comment: I'm not a node expert but the way `JS` works which seems like the `return arr` is being retuened before the function gets executed, it's async, right? Check [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/deferred).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

reader.on is async you are returning it before the conclusion your code should be

```
    newDefineWord.prototype.define = function(searchTerm, cb) {
          var arr = [];
          this.reader.on('line', function (line) {

              if (line.search(searchTerm)!== -1) {            
                arr.push(line);
                console.log(arr);
              }
        });
        this.reader.on('close',function(){
            cb(arr)
        })

    }

    var word = new newDefineWord(reader);
    word.define('libro', function(arr){
        console.log(arr);

    })
```

Additionally if you do not want to use callbacks you can use promises or generators

Comment: Thanks will take a look at promises and emitters also, currently learning a lot at the moment just from this small exercise